# NAV needs to justify across page

Tags: html, css, nav

My navbar has a background set and has 22px of padding on the left and right side of my links. Because of this not being exact I have a little space on the right hand side that does not match up with the below content.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Bikes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Components</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Featured Merch</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nutrition</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then my CSS

```
 nav ul {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

 nav li {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    nav a {
        color: white;
        background-color: #4c4d4f;
        padding: 2px 22px;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        color: #FDB813;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

First, the `display: inline` caused the space you mentioned. Replace that with `float: left`.

Then you may need the spaces between `<li>`s:

```
nav li {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

And remove margin of the last `<li>`:

```
nav li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Then you have the behavior you want.

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6wy8/)